# 4 of Einstein equations without 2nd order time derivative

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity

This question is related to [my previous one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/89969/6-independent-einstein-field-equations) and it was a homework problem and was due two weeks ago.

*Problem*：prove that four of Einsteins' equations
$$
G_{0\nu} = 8\pi T_{0\nu} 
$$
have to 2nd order time derivative and thus serve as constraint equations.

I found a nice argument in Carroll's [lecture notes](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9712019), 
$$
\partial_0 G^{0\nu} =-\partial_i G^{i\nu} -\Gamma^{\mu}_{\mu\lambda} G^{\lambda \nu} -\Gamma^{\nu}_{\mu\lambda} G^{\mu \lambda}  
$$
since there are at most 2nd order time derivative on the RHS, $G^{0\nu}$ has at most 1st order time derivative.

But $G_{0\nu}$ is not proportional to $G^{0\nu}$ for a general metric. In fact $G_{0\nu} = G^{\mu\lambda}g_{0\mu} g_{\lambda \mu}$ contains ingredients other than $G^{0\mu}$.

Of course we can use $G_{\mu\nu}{}^{;\nu}=0$  to prove that there is not 2nd order $\partial^0$ in $G_{0\nu}$. But now "spatial derivative" here is a mixed derivative,  $\partial^i = g^{i\mu} \partial_\mu$. Two such spatial derivative could contain 2nd order time derivative.

I suspect that only the $G^{0\nu}$ version is true. However a talk [here](http://www.qgf.uni-jena.de/gk_quantenmedia/Texte/rinne090616-p-67.pdf) use $G_{0\nu}$ instead of $G^{0\nu}$ for the constraint equations, where they didn't provide a proof.

Now let me compute it explicitly in the explicit form, while terms containing at most 1st order time derivative will be dropped. So the sign $\sim$ really means both sides have the same term of 2nd order time derivative.

$$R_{0\nu} = R^{\alpha}{}_{0\alpha\nu} \sim \Gamma^{\alpha}{}_{0\nu,\alpha}-\Gamma^{\alpha}{}_{0\alpha,\nu} \sim \Gamma^{0}{}_{0\nu,0} -\Gamma^{\alpha}{}_{0\alpha,\nu}$$

$$R \sim \Gamma^{\alpha\beta}{}_{\alpha,\beta} - \Gamma^{\alpha\beta}{}_{\beta,\alpha} \sim \Gamma^{\alpha 0}{}_{\alpha,0} - \Gamma^{0\alpha}{}_{\alpha,0}$$
$$G_{0\nu} =\Gamma^{0}{}_{0\nu,0} -\Gamma^{\alpha}{}_{0\alpha,\nu} - \frac{1}{2}g_{0\nu}(\Gamma^{\alpha 0}{}_{\alpha,0} - \Gamma^{0\alpha}{}_{\alpha,0})  $$

First evaluate things in the parenthesis, namely the scalar curvature,

$$\Gamma^{\alpha 0}{}_{\alpha 0} = (g^{0\beta} \Gamma^{\alpha}{}_{\beta\alpha})_{,0} = (g^{0\beta} \ln(|g|^{\frac{1}{2}})_{,\beta})_{,0} \sim g^{00} \ln(|g|^{\frac{1}{2}})_{,00}  $$

$$\Gamma^{\alpha}{}_{0\alpha} = g^{\alpha\beta} \Gamma^{0}{}_{\alpha\beta}=\frac{1}{2}g^{\alpha\beta} g^{0\mu}(g_{\mu\alpha,\beta} + g_{\mu\beta,\alpha} - g_{\alpha\beta, \mu} ) =  -g^{\alpha\beta} g^{0\mu}{}_{,\beta}g_{\mu\alpha} - \frac{1}{2} g^{\alpha\beta} g^{0\mu} g_{\alpha\beta,\mu} = -g^{0\mu}{}_{,\mu} -g^{0\mu}\ln(|g|^{\frac{1}{2}})_{,\mu} \sim -g^{00}_{,0} - g^{00}\ln(|g|^{\frac{1}{2}})_{,0}  $$

and thus,
$$R \sim 2g^{00}\ln(|g|^{\frac{1}{2}})_{,00}  + g^{00}{}_{,00} $$

Now for Ricci tensor, 
$$\Gamma^{0}{}_{0\nu} = \frac{1}{2}g^{0\mu}(g_{\mu 0, \nu} + g_{\mu \nu, 0} - g_{0\nu, \mu} ) 
\sim - \frac{1}{2}g^{0\mu}{}_{,0}( g_{\mu 0} \delta_{\nu 0} + g_{\mu\nu} ) -\frac{1}{2} g^{00}g_{0\nu,0}  $$
$$\Gamma^{\alpha}{}_{0\alpha,\nu} \sim \delta_{0\nu} \ln(|g|^{\frac{1}{2}})_{,00}$$

Hence,
$$R_{0\nu} \sim - \frac{1}{2}g^{0\mu}{}_{,00}( g_{\mu 0} \delta_{\nu 0} + g_{\mu\nu} ) -\frac{1}{2} g^{00}g_{0\nu,00} 
- \delta_{0\nu} \ln(|g|^{\frac{1}{2}})_{,00}
$$

Finally the Einstein tensor
$$G_{0\nu} \sim - \frac{1}{2}g^{0\mu}{}_{,00}( g_{\mu 0} \delta_{\nu 0} + g_{\mu\nu} ) -\frac{1}{2} g^{00}g_{0\nu,00} 
- \delta_{0\nu} \ln(|g|^{\frac{1}{2}})_{,00} - g_{0\nu} g^{00}\ln(|g|^{\frac{1}{2}})_{,00}  -\frac{1}{2}g_{0\nu}  g^{00}{}_{,00}$$

Maybe there are some subtle mistakes in the calculation(please point them out), but I can't simply it any further and at along show it $\sim 0$.

**My questions**

1. Is the "$G_{0\nu}$" version of the statement right?
2. Is it possible to prove it using the trick that similar to that of Carroll's?
3. Any mistake I made in the explicit calculation? Or any magic identity could make it $\sim 0$